# Use forward slash before template variable

Tags: scala, twirl

For quite some time I am now trying to get the following template to work with twirl:

```
    @for(service <- services) {
        location /grpc/@service {
            grpc_pass @service:8088;
        }
    }
```

`services` is a `List[String]`. While the template is properly converted into a scala template, that scala template does not compile:

```
nginx.template.scala:40: type mismatch;
 found   : play.twirl.api.TxtFormat.Appendable
    (which expands to)  play.twirl.api.Txt
 required: Int
```

With line 40 being:

```
      """),format.raw/*18.9*/("""location /grpc/"""),_display_(/*18.25*/service/*18.32*/ {_display_(Seq[Any](format.raw/*18.34*/("""
```

Checking that file out in IntelliJ does not show any error on that line. Changing it to `location @service` works as expected.

Do I need to escape the forward slash somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to fix the issue:

```
location /grpc/@{service}
```